# Estimating the value of a integral using Simpson's Rule

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification, numerical-methods

Problem:
Find an estimate of the following integral with $n = 4$ using Simpson's rule.
$$ \int_0^2 x^4 \,\, dx $$
Answer:
Let $S$ be the estimate of the integral. The general formula for $S$ is
$$ S = \dfrac{h}{3} \left( f(x_0) + 4f(x_1) + 2f(x_2) + ... 4f(x_{n-1}) + f(x_n) ) \right) $$
where
$$ h = \dfrac{b-a}{n} $$
In this case, we have:
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= x^4 \\
h &= \dfrac{ 2 - 0}{4} = \dfrac{1}{2} \\
f(x_0) &= f(0) = 0 \\
f(x_1) &= f\left(  \dfrac{1}{2}\right)  = \dfrac{1}{16} \\
f(x_2) &= f(1) = 1 \\
f(x_3) &= f\left(  \dfrac{3}{2} \right)  = \dfrac{ 81}{16} \\
f(x_4) &= f(2) = 16 \\
\end{align*}
Now we can compute the value of $S$.
\begin{align*}
S &= \dfrac{1}{6}
 \left( 0 + 4 \left( \dfrac{1}{16} \right)  + 2 \left( 1 \right) 
  + 4 \left( \dfrac{ 81}{16} \right) + \left( 16 \right)  ) \right) \\
%
S &= \dfrac{1}{6}
 \left( \dfrac{4}{16}  + 2 + 4 \left( \dfrac{ 81}{16} \right) + 16 \right) \\
%
S &= \dfrac{1}{6} \left( \dfrac{1}{4}  + 2 + \dfrac{ 81}{4} + 16 \right) \\
S &= \dfrac{1}{6} \left( \dfrac{ 82}{4} + 18 \right)
 = \dfrac{1}{6} \left( \dfrac{ 41}{2} + \dfrac{36}{2} \right) \\
S &= \dfrac{ 77}{12} \\
S &\doteq 6.4167
\end{align*}

As a partial check, I will now find the value exactly.
\begin{align*}
\int_0^2 x^4 \,\, dx &= \dfrac{x^5}{5} \Big|_0^2 = \dfrac{32}{5} \\
\int_0^2 x^4 \,\, dx &= 6.4
\end{align*}

Is my solution correct?

I am now thinking my solution is incorrect for the following reason:

Now let's look at the magnitude of the error which I will represent by $|E_s|$. We have:
\begin{align*}
|E_s| &= 6.4167 - 6.4 \\
|E_s| &= 0.0167
\end{align*}
The error estimate for Simpson's rule is:
$$ |E_s| \leq \dfrac{b-a}{180}h^4 M$$
where $M$ is any unper bound for the values of $|f^{[4]}|$ on the interval $[a,b]$. We have:
\begin{align*}
f'(x) &= 4x^3 \\
f''(x) &= 12x^2 \\
f'''(x) &= 24x \\
f^{[4]} &= 12 \\
M &= 12 \\
\dfrac{b-a}{180}h^4 M &= \left( \dfrac{2-0}{180}\right) \left(  \dfrac{1}{2}\right) ^4 (12) \\
\dfrac{b-a}{180}h^4 M &= \left( \dfrac{1}{90}\right) \left(  \dfrac{1}{2}\right) ^4 (12) \\
\dfrac{b-a}{180}h^4 M &= \dfrac{12}{90(16)} = \dfrac{3}{90(4)} \\
\dfrac{b-a}{180}h^4 M &= \dfrac{1}{120} \\
|E_s| &\leq  \dfrac{1}{120} \doteq 0.0083333
\end{align*}
However, $|E_s| = 0.0167$ hence I conclude that I did something wrong. What did I do wrong?

Comment: I didn't check all your arithmetic, but the general set-out looks good.

Comment: The final result is correct.

Comment: M = 24, not 12 - you slipped going from the third derivative to the fourth.

Comment: @MichaelLugo You are right and when I use the correct value for $M$ I see the error is within the desired range. If you could tell me that my solution is correct as an answer, I will accept the answer.

Comment: @Bob done - see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $f(x) = x^4$ and so, taking derivatives, $f^\prime(x) = 4x^3, f^{\prime\prime} = 12x^2, f^{\prime\prime\prime} = 24x, f^{(4)}(x) = 24$ (not 12).  So $M = 24$, which gives

$$|E_s| \le {b-a \over 180} h^4 M = {2-0 \over 180} \left( {1 \over 2} \right)^4 {24} = {1 \over 60}. $$

Answer (score 0):

Now let's look at the magnitude of the error which I will represent by $|E_s|$. We have:
\begin{align*}
|E_s| &= 6.4167 - 6.4 \\
|E_s| &= 0.0167
\end{align*}
The error estimate for Simpson's rule is:
$$ |E_s| \leq \dfrac{b-a}{180}h^4 M$$
where $M$ is any unper bound for the values of $|f^{[4]}|$ on the interval $[a,b]$. We have:
\begin{align*}
f'(x) &= 4x^3 \\
f''(x) &= 12x^2 \\
f'''(x) &= 24x \\
f^{[4]} &= 24 \\
M &= 24 \\
\dfrac{b-a}{180}h^4 M &= \left( \dfrac{2-0}{180}\right) \left(  \dfrac{1}{2}\right) ^4 (24) \\
\dfrac{b-a}{180}h^4 M &= \left( \dfrac{1}{90}\right) \left(  \dfrac{1}{2}\right) ^4 (24) \\
\dfrac{b-a}{180}h^4 M &= \left( \dfrac{12}{45(16)}\right) \\
\dfrac{b-a}{180}h^4 M &=  \left( \dfrac{1}{60}\right) \\
|E_s| &\leq  \dfrac{1}{60} \doteq 0.0166667
\end{align*}
Hence I conclude that they error is within the expected range and the original solution to the problem posted is correct.